# "param $slug referenced, but not provided"

Tags: next.js, sanity

when I try to fetch data inside sanity vision, I get this error:

```
param $slug referenced, but not provided
*[_type == "post" && slug.current == $slug][0]{
-------------------------------------^^^^
Line:   0
Column: 37
```

[this is the SS of the sanity vision](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J0Y7b.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the PARAMS panel in the bottom-left, you’ll want to specify a `slug` param.

```
{
  “slug”: “some-slug”
}
```